# how to print string before and after substring then add new string into old string?

Tags: java, string, substring

I am trying to make a program that can read the string before and after substring then ask user to add a new string and print the new string the position that user like here is a sample:

> ```
> Enter a long string: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
>
> Enter a substring: jumped
>
> Length of your string: 44
>
> Length of your substring: 6
>
> Starting position of your substring in string: 20
>
> String before your substring: The quick brown fox
>
> String after your substring:  over the lazy dog
>
> Enter a position between 0 and 43: 18
>
> The character at position 18 is x
>
> Enter a replacement string: leaped
>
> Your new string is: The quick brown fox leaped over the lazy dog
> ```

and here is my code that i am doing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner name = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a long string: ");
        String username = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a substring: ");
        String subname = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Length of your string: "+ username.length());
        System.out.println("Length of your substring: " + subname.length());
        System.out.println( "Starting position of your substring in string: "+ username.indexOf(subname));

        System.out.println("Enter a replacement string: ");
        String newname = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your new string is: "+ );


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string before the entered substring should just be `username.substring(0, username.indexOf(subname)`, and then the string after should just be `username.substring(username.indexOf(subname) + subname.length)`. Then just print the new string in between those two substrings.

Comment: when i add a new string between those string the user substring is delete here is the code i add: 'System.out.println("Enter a replacement string: ");
  String newname = name.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Your new string is: " + username.substring(0, username.indexOf(subname))+ " "+ newname+ " "+username.substring(username.indexOf(subname)+subname.length()));
  '

Comment: Yes, that should do it. Although you shouldn't need to add spaces between each component string.

Comment: this is what it look like http://i58.tinypic.com/28gryv8.png
when it print the new string it delete the old string

Answer (score 1):

So:

```
int index = text.indexOf(substring);
String left = text.substring(0, index);
String right = text.substring(index + substring.length());
String replacement = name.nextLine();
String newText = left + replacement + right;
```